# Finding Include view and updating TextView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which inside of it i have

```
<include layout="@layout/card" android:id="@+id/card" />
<include layout="@layout/card" android:id="@+id/card1" />
<include layout="@layout/card" android:id="@+id/card2" />
```

And my card xml is just a simple card as below

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Item Color"
                android:textColor="#222"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

What im trying to do in my java fragment is loading the first card include and chnage its text view text 
This is what i tried but it returns null

```
View card1 =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.card1);
              TextView ct1 = (TextView) card1.findViewById(R.id.title);
```

So how can i achieve my goal or fix this problem? 
Thanks for your time and help , appreciate it 
**** update :
Heres the whole fragment

```
public class Home_Fragment extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       //Inflate the layout for this fragment
         ViewGroup card1 = (ViewGroup)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.card1);
              TextView ct1 = (TextView) card1.findViewById(R.id.title);
              ct1.setText("hey :P");

      return inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.findViewById(R.id.card1);` on the content view of the Fragment instead on `getActivity()`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View contentView = inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
   //Inflate the layout for this fragment
     ViewGroup card1 = (ViewGroup)  contentView.findViewById(R.id.card1);
          TextView ct1 = (TextView) card1.findViewById(R.id.title);
          ct1.setText("hey :P");

  return contentView;
```

}

Comment: I did and same thing 11-04 22:03:28.781 E/AndroidRuntime(30131): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mr.aide.theme.engine/mr.aide.theme.engine.ThemeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.ViewGroup.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Heres the code i tried ViewGroup card1 = (ViewGroup)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.card1);

Comment: Ok i will try tnx

Comment: ViewGroup card1 = (ViewGroup)  Home_Fragment.findViewById(R.id.card1);   i tried it but it gave unknown method findViewByid of packageid.Home_Fragment

Comment: When you inflate the view in onCreateView find the card there

Comment: I do have that i will add the fragment in question